# FacesContext loosing its context value only for first time

Tags: jsf, facelets, jsf-1.2

I have one Facelets page with one `h:commandLink`.

```
<h:commandLink value="#{View} &#187;" 
    onclick="return myJavaScript('#{myBean.param1}');">
</h:commandLink>

function myJavaScript(paramReceived)
{
   var relPath = "/myWarName/Pages/myReceiptPage.jsf?"
                    + myActionValue;
    billWindow = window.open(relPath, '', 'width=' + width + ',height='
                    + height + ',top=' + top + ',left=' + left
                    + ',scrollbars=1,resizable=1');
    billWindow.focus();
}
```

Below is my `myReceiptPage.xhtml` page code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <head>
    </head>
      <f:view>
          <body>
             <h:form>
               <ui:insert>
                           <ui:include src="/someOtherPage.xhtml" />
               </ui:insert>

                <h:outputText value="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestParameterMap.UserID}" /> 

                          </h:form>
                     <body>
             </f:view>
      <div>
```

When I click on `h:commandLink` , Java Script gets invoked and a Window Opens, but with below Exception **only for the first time**. From second time onwards, when I again click on the `h:commandLink` , window opens with no Exception and data is properly populated.

When I click on `h:commandLink` PhaseListener is getting invoked, which is calling one method. Below is the code,

```
public void getUserId()
    {
        try
        {
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
            ExternalContext externalContext = context.getExternalContext();
                    //Code continues
        }
            Catch(Exception E)
            {
              //Am getting to know the exception here
             }
      }
```

Below is the exception (which is displayed on the Window),

```
javax.faces.FacesException: javax.el.ELException: /view.xhtml @192,150 userID="#{myBean.userID}": Error reading 'userID' on type com.myBean
        at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:187)
        at org.richfaces.component.UITabPanel.getValue(UITabPanel.java:103)
        at org.richfaces.renderkit.TabPanelRendererBase.encodeTabs(TabPanelRendererBase.java:309)
        at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.TabPanelRenderer.doEncodeBegin(TabPanelRenderer.java:228)
        at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.TabPanelRenderer.doEncodeBegin(TabPanelRenderer.java:180)
        at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeBegin(RendererBase.java:100)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:813)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:928)
        at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:148)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:930)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:933)
        at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:592)
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:189)
        at org.jboss.portletbridge.application.PortletViewHandler.renderView(PortletViewHandler.java:247)
        at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
```

What could be possible cause for this?

**EDIT** : Contents of `view.xhtml` is pasted below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk">
<head>
</head>
<h:form id="myFormId">
<ui:insert>
    <ui:include src="/myWarName/Pages/someOtherPage.xhtml" />  //Guess, problem is with this include. 
//This include is also there in myReceiptPage.xhtml page.
</ui:insert>

<rich:tabPanel selectedTab="#{myBean.getSelectedTab}">
    <rich:tab name="Tab Name">
        <h:panelGroup>
            <ui:insert>
               <ui:include src="somePage1.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup>
            <ui:insert>
                <ui:include src="somePage2.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </h:panelGroup>
</rich:tab>
</h:form
</html>
```

**To add to Exception list** : `<rich:tabPanel selectedTab="#{someBean.getSelectedTab}">`

`getSelectedTab` method above looks like this,

```
public class myBean implements Serializable{
 public String getSelectedSubTab()
 {
   FacesContext con=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();  
   ExternalContext externalContext = con.getExternalContext();
   String remoteUserId = externalContext.getRemoteUser();
   User user = UserServiceUtil.getUserById(Long.parseLong(remoteUserId));
   this.userID = user.getScreenName();          
 }
}
```

Comment: Is this the whole of the stack trace? It looks like there's an underlying cause that's making EL choke.

Comment: Well we don't see `view.xhtml` here, and place here is problematic EL.

Comment: @kolossus Apart from that exception, am also getting NullPointerException.  And this has been updated in my question.

Comment: @partlov Have included `view.xhtml` code also. Have commented in one place where I suspect that there is some problem

Comment: @VikasV `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` will return null usually when you're making that call within a non-managed bean. Is `someBean` properly declared and scoped?

Comment: @VikasV also make sure that view.xhtml is serviced by FacesServlet

Comment: @kolossus Thanks. How can I check if view.xhtml is serviced by `FacesServlet`? And BTW `someBean` is properly declared and its in Session scope.

Comment: The line `FacesContext con=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();` can impossibly throw a `NullPointerException` as it's a static method call. Don't you rather mean that it returned `null`?

Comment: ya sorry its actually `null` there. Have updated the code in question above which follows after that. NPE is thrown in the code which follows that.

Comment: @VikasV, does `view.xhtml` render properly in the browser? What packages are you importing the annotations from? Paste your entire managed bean here(make sure it's compilable).

Comment: @kolossus `view.xhtml` renders properly when `h:commandLink` is clicked for the second time. For the first time it throws `ElException` on the Window and `NPE` in the backend logs. I have edited my question now to include few more code for `getSelectedSubTab()` method. At the line `this.userID` NPE is thrown in backend logs. Am not using any annotations in Bean.

Comment: So.. It's just `user` which is `null`? (and you being identifying the problem completely wrong?)

Answer (score 0):

I must say that I still don't see expression `#{myBean.userID}` in any xhtml file, but problem is probably because your getter method `getUserId()` is declared as `void`, so property `userId` here is considered non-readable. You have to return property from getter.